# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top breaks when increasing height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

So I have a navbar-fixed-top that's set to collapse at 992px, most mobile screens wont collapse at anything lower than that anymore. Well, from what I can tell anyway. The problem is that when I try increase the navbar height at the lower screen width, I cant vertically center anything on the navbar - being the placeholder for the logo to come or the dropdown button. I'm also struggling to increase the size of the dropdown button no matter what I try. Finally as soon as I increase the height of the navbar, when I click the dropdown menu, the background image disappears yet it works fine with the default height. I'm really hoping someone knows a trick or two as it seems lots of people are struggling with navbar-fixed-top.

Here's the html setup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsed-navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsed-navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a ng-href="#link">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a ng-href="#link">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a ng-href="#link">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a ng-href="#link">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><img class="img-circle nav-profile-image" src="images/default_pic.png" /></li>
                    <li><a ng-href="#link">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

And here's the CSS so far:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {    
    .nav-profile-image {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar {
        height: 80px;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .nav-profile-image {
        height: 40px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
}

.navbar {
    background-image: url('../images/noise-background.jpg');
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have overlapping media queries. Your second should start at 993px.

Comment: Ah, not sure why I didn't see that. Fixing it didn't change anything at all though.

Comment: Do you have a live example or could you make a fiddle?